# is there another function can instead of live() in jquery 1.26?

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

```
$('#content').find('p:eq(0)').append('<span class="more"> | more</span><span class="less"> | less</span>')
$('p:gt(0)').hide();

$('.more, .less').live('click', function() {
    $('#content').find('p:gt(0)').slideToggle();
    $('.more, .less').toggle();
})
```

the jquery is 1.26, it haven't have a suppport to the `live()` function. is there another function can instead of it. or alter the code to get the effect?

i using drupal-6, if i don't want to upgrade the jquery. is there a way to get the effect?

Comment: You should upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a normal `click` handler to `.content`, then check whether `$(e.target).is('.more, .less')`.

This is how `live()` works internally.

Comment: $('#content').click(function()$(e.target).is('.more, .less'); 
    $('#content').find('p:gt(0)').slideToggle();
    $('.more, .less').toggle();  i put this code, instead. but it can't work

Comment: You need to use an `if` statement.  Also, you missed a `{`.

Comment: thank you. this is the whole code. it still can't work. $('#content').find('p:eq(0)').append('<span class="more"> | more</span><span class="less"> | less</span>')
$('p:gt(0)').hide();

$('#content').click(function(){
    if($(e.target).is('.more, .less')){
    
     $('#content').find('p:gt(0)').slideToggle();
    $('.more, .less').toggle();
    }

})

Answer (score 1):

there is no `.live()` in jQuery 1.26, so you must be looking for [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

Answer (score 0):

After you append the span, you can use $('.more').bind('click',function() { etc }) But you cant declare the .bind method on document.ready unless you added the clickable element before.

Comment: This will add extra handlers to existing elements.  Call `unbind` too.